# Strip elasticSearch Markdown (html...) tags

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch as our primary backend technology.

We need to save a field's entity which is formatted using markdown lightweight markup language.

So, we are considering two options:

- Save full text (markdown labels included): The problem here is later we are going to deal with markdown labels when I search is requested.
- Clean markdown labels (only store the content): The problem is we are going to save the complete text in another backend support.

Is there some analizer?
As far I've been able to figure out, there are some `strips` concepts I don't quite to understand how it works.

Thanks.